# Python 3.5.1 error ImportError: No module named '_tkinter' python3

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-12.04

I am using python 3.5.1 on ubuntu 12.04
As seen on a different page on stack overflow, I installed the module using 
    sudo apt-get install python3-tk
But I am still getting the same error. I have attached a screenshot. Please help me out.[The code and the error I faced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k70mj.png)

Comment: Have you followed the steps under 'Step 1 - can _tkinter be imported?'? https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter You may also want to try installing it with pip, that may compile the C extension your python is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a ubuntu machine to test it on, however, on my windows machine using 3.5.1, I was able to import tkinter using

```
import tkinter
```

rather than

```
import _tkinter
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please check the screenshot I have attached. I have shown the code in the text editor also. I have imported turtle module.